# Assigning background color to row available in data using react-data-table-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-table-component

I have `DataTable` of  `react-data-table-component` data coming from backend have a color property for each row. I have to use that color. I tried with conditionalStyles and custom styles but didn't worked.

```js
const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'some title',
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'some title 2',
      color: 'green'
    },
  ]
const columns = [
    {
      name: 'Title',
      selector: (row) => row.title,
    },
]
<DataTable columns={columns} data={data} conditionalStyles={conditionalStyles}/>
```

I tried but these didn't worked for me. the color coming from backend API response can have any color so the frontend doesn't know the color before hand

```js
 const customStyles = {
    rows: {
        style: (row, rowIndex) => ({
            backgroundColor: row.color
        })
    },
  };

  
 const conditionalStyles = {
    when: row => row.color,
    style: row => ({
      backgroundColor: row => row.color ? row.color : ''
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys the problem is sorted out seems like I was not generating the correct conditionalRowStyle here is correct structure.

```js
  const conditionalRowStyles = [
    {
      when: (row) => true,
      style: row => ({
        backgroundColor: row.color,
      })
    }
  ];
```